# Scraping to a text file but it won't write unless duplicated. Python 3.7 ChromeDriver BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

This code was working 4-5 hours ago and now it is duplicating what I want it to write to the file. The obvious things I tried was commenting out the file.write lines or the print line under it which results in a blank text file. I have tried with the open line various parameters such as a+, a, w, and w+ while commenting out one of the 2 aforementioned lines and it still is blank. Hopefully someone can figure out where I have messed up and help me correct the issue.

Another question I have is how I would navigate to the next chapter after getting the current one copied, but if I have to make a new question for that I will. Also if you have any suggestions to make the code better minus defs which I will be adding later (after the script is done) let me know.

Here is the code so far ::

```
#! python3
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def Close():
    driver.stop_client()
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'E:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

# start raw html
NovelName = 'Novel/Isekai-Maou-to-Shoukan-Shoujo-Dorei-Majutsu'
BaseURL = 'https://novelplanet.com/'
url = '%(U)s/%(N)s' % {'U': BaseURL, "N": NovelName}

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["ignore-certificate-errors"])
options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
options.add_argument('start-maximized') # 
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
driver.get(url)

# wait for title not be equal to "Please wait 5 seconds..."
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.title != "Please wait 5 seconds...")

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
# End raw html

# Start get first chapter html coded
i=0
for chapterLink in soup.find_all(class_='rowChapter'):
    i+=1
cLink = chapterLink.find('a').contents[0].strip()
print(driver.title)
# end get first chapter html coded

# start navigate to first chapter
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(cLink)
link.click()
# end navigate to first chapter

# start copy of chapter and add to a file
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.title != "Please wait 5 seconds...")
print(driver.title)
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
readables = soup.find(id='divReadContent')
text = readables.text.strip().replace('○','0').replace('×','x').replace('《',' <<').replace('》','>> ').replace('「','"').replace('」','"')
name = driver.title
file_name = (name.replace('Read ',"").replace(' - NovelPlanet',"")+'.txt')
print(file_name)

with open(file_name,'a+') as file:
    print(text,file=file)

lastURL = driver.current_url.replace('https://novelplanet.com','')
# end copy of chapter and add to a file

# start goto next chapter if exists then return to copy chapter else Close()

# end goto next chapter if exists then return to copy chapter else Close()

Close()
#EOF
```

Edit:
Changed the above code to use the suggestion below. Took me about an hour to realize you can use the modifiers with it considering the docs did not have that information in it, which was also the reason I strayed from the easy path.

Now to figure out how to navigate through the pages there are 6 of `<div class="4u 12u(small)">` the 2nd and 5th one are comboboxes/option boxes which I doubt will be easy to use. The 1st and 4th are previous chapters and the 3rd and 6th are the  next chapters. When the previous button or the next button have no where to go they say `<div class="4u 12u(small)">&nbsp;</div>`. Anyone know of a way to selectively choose either the 3rd or 6th button out of all 6 options as well as a way to kill the program when the end has been reached?

Comment: read [reading-and-writing-files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and use `with open(...) as f: ...`  - store the result of `readables.text.strip().replace('○','0').replace('×','x').replace('《',' <<').replace('》','>> ').replace('「','"').replace('」','"')` in a variable and reuse it ... or better make it a function working on a dict of stuff to replace

Comment: Never used dictionaries for really anything but I did do as you suggested after fighting with it to figure out a stupidly (undocumented) easy truth about the `with open` command. So thank you for the help.